# Stream.findFirst different than Optional.of?

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

Let's say I have two classes and two methods:

```
class Scratch {
    private class A{}
    private class B extends A{}

    public Optional<A> getItems(List<String> items){
        return items.stream()
             .map(s -> new B())
             .findFirst();
    }

    public Optional<A> getItems2(List<String> items){
        return Optional.of(
            items.stream()
                 .map(s -> new B())
                 .findFirst()
                 .get()
        );
    }
}
```

Why does `getItems2` compile while `getItems` gives compiler error

```
incompatible types: java.util.Optional<Scratch.B> cannot be converted to java.util.Optional<Scratch.A>
```

So when I `get` the value of the `Optional` returned by `findFirst` and wrap it again with `Optional.of` the compiler recognizes the inheritance but not if I use directly the result of `findFirst`.

Comment: Simpler to reproduce `Optional<A> a = Optional.of(new B());
        Optional<A> b = Stream.of(new B()).findFirst();` if I get you correct. Mostly, the reason is type inferred from the context for `Optional.of` as its signature implies `<T> Optional<T> of(T value)`

Comment: @nullpointer yes, you’ve created the minimal example, but I suppose, the examples of the question are closer to the OP’s original code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An `Optional<B>` is not a subtype of `Optional<A>`. Unlike other programming languages, Java’s generic type system does not know “read only types” or “output type parameters”, so it doesn’t understand that `Optional<B>` only provides an instance of `B` and could work at places where an `Optional<A>` is required.

When we write a statement like

```
Optional<A> o = Optional.of(new B());
```

Java’s type inference uses the target type to determine that we want

```
Optional<A> o = Optional.<A>of(new B());
```

which is valid as `new B()` can be used where an instance of `A` is required.

The same applies to

```
return Optional.of(
        items.stream()
             .map(s -> new B())
             .findFirst()
             .get()
    );
```

where the method’s declared return type is used to infer the type arguments to the `Optional.of` invocation and passing the result of `get()`, an instance of `B`, where `A` is required, is valid.

Unfortunately, this target type inference doesn’t work through chained invocations, so for

```
return items.stream()
     .map(s -> new B())
     .findFirst();
```

it is not used for the `map` call. So for the `map` call, the type inference uses the type of `new B()` and its result type will be `Stream<B>`. The second problem is that `findFirst()` is not generic, calling it on a `Stream<T>` invariably produces a `Optional<T>` (and Java’s generics does not allow to declare a type variable like `<R super T>`, so it is not even possible to produce an `Optional<R>` with the desired type here).

→ The solution is to provide an explicit type for the `map` call:

```
public Optional<A> getItems(List<String> items){
    return items.stream()
         .<A>map(s -> new B())
         .findFirst();
}
```

Just for completeness, as said, `findFirst()` is not generic and hence, can’t use the target type. Chaining a generic method allowing a type change would also fix the problem:

```
public Optional<A> getItems(List<String> items){
    return items.stream()
         .map(s -> new B())
         .findFirst()
         .map(Function.identity());
}
```

But I recommend using the solution of providing an explicit type for the `map` invocation.

Comment: Hi Holger. That is even better as my originally accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54801033/1571117

Answer (score 8):

The issue you have is with inheritance for generics.
Optional< B > doesn't extend Optional< A >, so it can't be returned as such.

I'd imagine that something like this:

```
public Optional<? extends A> getItems( List<String> items){
    return items.stream()
        .map(s -> new B())
        .findFirst();
}
```

Or:

```
public Optional<?> getItems( List<String> items){
    return items.stream()
        .map(s -> new B())
        .findFirst();
}
```

Would work fine, depending on your needs.

Edit: escaping some characters

Comment: I will accept this answer as it also provides the information how the first method would work (althogh I did not explicitely asked I am happy with the solution)

Comment: There’s a [guideline for Generics use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) and it says: “*Using a wildcard as a return type should be avoided because it forces programmers using the code to deal with wildcards*” and from my practical experience, it’s a good advice. After all, returning `Optional<A>` can be easily achieved, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802049/2711488).

Answer (score 6):

An `Optional<B>` is **not** a sub-class of `Optional<A>`.

In the first case, you have a `Stream<B>`, so `findFirst` returns an `Optional<B>`, which cannot be converted to an `Optional<A>`.

In the second case, you have a stream pipeline that returns an instance of `B`. When you pass that instance to `Optional.of()`, the compiler sees that the return type of the method is `Optional<A>`, so `Optional.of()` returns an `Optional<A>` (since an `Optional<A>` can hold an instance of `B` as its value (since `B` extends `A`)).

Answer (score 3):

Look at this similar example:

```
Optional<A> optA = Optional.of(new B()); //OK
Optional<B> optB = Optional.of(new B()); //OK
Optional<A> optA2 = optB;                //doesn't compile
```

You can make the second method fail by rewriting it as:

```
public Optional<A> getItems2(List<String> items) {
    return Optional.<B>of(items.stream().map(s -> new B()).findFirst().get());
}
```

This is simply because generic types are invariant.

---

Why the difference? See the declaration of `Optional.of`:

```
public static <T> Optional<T> of(T value) {
    return new Optional<>(value);
}
```

The type of the optional is picked up from the target of the assignment (or return type in this case).

And `Stream.findFirst()`:

```
//T comes from Stream<T>, it's not a generic method parameter
Optional<T> findFirst();
```

In this case, however, `return items.stream().map(s -> new B()).findFirst();` doesn't type the result of `.findFirst()` based on the declared return type of `getItems` (`T` is strictly based on the type argument of `Stream<T>`)

Answer (score 2):

If the class B inherits class A, that doesn't mean Optional inherits Optional. Optional is a different class.