# Why does Optional.map make this assignment work?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, option-type

```
Optional<ArrayList<String>> option = Optional.of(new ArrayList<>());

Optional<ArrayList<?>> doesntWork = option;

Optional<ArrayList<?>> works = option.map(list -> list);
```

The first attempted assignment does not compile, but the second one with the `map` does. It feels like the `map` shouldn't actually accomplish anything, but for some reason it turns my `Optional<ArrayList<String>>` into an `Optional<ArrayList<?>>`. Is there some sort of implicit cast going on?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you look into the code of `map` and follow all the method calls, you'll see that `option.map(list -> list)` ends up returning `new Optional<>(option.get())`. So you can replace your last assignment with:

```
Optional<ArrayList<?>> works = new Optional<>(option.get());
```

This creates a new `Optional<ArrayList<?>>` and initializes its `value` instance variable (whose type is `ArrayList<?>`) with the `ArrayList<String>` returned by `map.get()`. This is a valid assignment.

> Is there some sort of implicit cast going on?

No, `map` returns a new `Optional` instance. It doesn't cast the original instance on which it was called.

Here's the chain of method calls:

```
option.map(list -> list)
```

returns (since `option` is not empty)

```
Optional.ofNullable(mapper.apply(value))
```

which in your case is the same as

```
Optional.ofNullable(value)
```

which returns (since the value is not null):

```
Optional.of(value)
```

which returns

```
new Optional<>(value)
```

Comment: Interesting, it just seems so strange that .map(list -> list) would do something, but yeah I suppose that makes sense.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802049/2711488). Its last code example uses `map(Function.identity())` where a direct assignment of the `Optional` is not possible. In the context of this question, `A` would `ArrayList<?>` and `B` would be `ArrayList<String>`.

Answer (score 10):

Well the first one does not work because generics are invariant, the only way to make them covariant is to add a bounded type for example:

```
 Optional<? extends ArrayList<String>> doesntWork = option;
```

that would compile.

And when you say that the `map` step should no accomplish anything is well, not correct. Look at the definition of `Optional::map`:

```
public <U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
    if (!isPresent()) {
        return empty();
    } else {
        return Optional.ofNullable(mapper.apply(value));
    }
}
```

roughly speaking it *does* transform from `Optional<T>` to `Optional<U>`...

Answer (score 0):

Your `option.map` has the signature

```
<ArrayList<?>> Optional<ArrayList<?>> java.util.Optional.map(Function<? super ArrayList<String>, ? extends ArrayList<?>> mapper)
```

So this

```
Optional<? extends ArrayList<?>> doesntWork = option;
```

does compile.

Comment: Yeah, that does compile, but I am more interested in why the map fixes it, this is just a simplistic version of what I am actually trying to do. In my actual code I am overriding a method that needs to return the equivalent of the Optional<ArrayList<?>> so just changing the type of that assignment doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

In your latter case the return type of the `Optional.map` method is implicitly determined by the type of your `works` variable. That's why there is a difference.

Comment: But how is that different from the first assignment? if the signature of map is determined to by the type declaration of the assignment to return Optional<ArrayList<?>> then that means the return of the lambda would be of the type ArrayList<?> and since my lambda is (at least as far as I can tell) returning the concrete type ArrayList<String> something somewhere is casting it after the fact I guess?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The difference is that the type of `option` is static where the return type of `Optional.map` is dynamically determined by the to be assigned variable.